# Query of select a datetime type column but getting back a UTC format data

Tags: javascript, sql-server, datetime

I store my data into SQL table as a local time format, like below

[image]

But then when I do select query of this data and display it on a dashboard, JavaScript returns it as UTC format like below

[image]

Is there a way for me when I select query the data is not converted?

Thanks

I did some readings how to convert it back to local time, but seems it didnt give a result as expected.

Comment: There are a lot of steps between your database and your front end. The conversion will be happening after that somewhere.

Comment: UTC is a time standard, not a format. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ is commonly referred to as ISO 8601 format (even though it's just one of the formats specified by ISO 8601, it's likely the most often used).